# Magento2 Admin Panel is not showing

Tags: magento2

[![I got this when i'm launching the admin panel for the first time **strong text**but it never loaded to the magneto2 admin panel! please tell me what to do?][1]][1]

Comment: are you on localhost?

Comment: Can you please update exact error message?